# How to calculate local orientation of child relative to parent from only global positions?

Tags: animation, rotation, skeletal-animation, three.js, euler-angles

I am trying visualize a human finger's pose with a 3D model in Three.js.

The 3D model is composed of 3 bones that represent the proximal, middle, and distal bones of the human finger, connected in that sequence.

For every frame, I have the global, 3D [x, y, z] positions/keypoints of the joints before and after each bone. The problem is I cannot set the model's pose with these positions/keypoints, I need to calculate **Euler** orientations (specifically yaw and pitch, with roll = 0) of each bone relative to its parent or the previous connected bone, in order to accurately transform the model's overall pose.

I know I can calculate the global yaw and pitch of any vector on a coordinate system via:

```
let direction = vector.normalize()
let yaw = Math.atan2(direction.x, direction.z);
let pitch = Math.asin(direction.y);
let roll = 0;
//bone.rotation.set(yaw, roll, pitch);
```

but again, these calculations don't work for local orientations.

---

lets say the positions/keypoints of the finger are **P1, P2, P3, P4** where **P1** is the position of the knuckle, **P2** and **P3** are the positions of the middle joints, and **P4** is the position of the tip of the finger

lets also say **E1, E2, E3** represent the absolute Euler orientations of the proximal, middle, and distal bone respectively, where **En** is the orientation of **En** relative to orientation **E(n-1)**

**How do I go about modifying my calculations to get the local rotations E1, E2, E3 from the global positions P1, P2, P3, P4?**

Comment: Can you not first convert into P1's space, using the global to local conversions you know, then call P1's space "global" and convert into P2's space using those same conversions again, and so on recursively down the finger until you get to the most deeply nested coordinate system?

Comment: I think that's where I need help on, converting from global space to Pn's space, so I can calculate the orientation of Pn+1 relative to Pn